# Best linear regression strategy

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have 11 variables (with 4 of them being sociodemographics) that predict my dependent variable. I want to perform linear regression analysis and I have two options. One: Exclude sociodemographics variables from regression analysis and just describe the participant's socidempgraphics in results and run simple linear regression for each variable separately. Two: Include sociodemographics and perform a hierarchical linear regression(which would result in seven regression models). What do you think the best option would be?

Comment: Although people tried their best, this is almost impossible to answer well. Your project -- your choices -- your need for a principled focus on what is interesting or helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why including sociodemographics in a hierarchical linear regression gives you seven regression models.  My very strong preference would be to fit the hierarchical linear model with demographics. But an equally strong preference would be to have a theory before I even looked at the data about which variables were important, why, and in what direction they would have an effect.   Otherwise you have an enormous model space and stand a very good chance of getting spurious but very good looking fits to your data.  I find Richard Berk one of the most thought provoking authorities on this subject who talks to users of the method rather than methodological theoreticians (e.g. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Regression-Analysis-Constructive-Quantitative-Techniques/dp/0761929045)

Comment: Thank you I'll consider your advice. Just for the clarification, I said it gives me seven models because the first model in the hierarchical consists of four sociodemographic variable and then one variable in each hierarchy(model) will be added until the last hierarchy which consists of 11 variables.

Comment: Ah OK. As I see this problem, you have seven candidate single variable models (a, b, c, d, e, f, g), but then you have 21 candidate two variable models (a+b, a+c, a+d, a+e, a+f, a+g, b+c, etc), then .... then seven 10 variable models.  This is a "huge" model space...which is why I don't like automatic model selection methods that just pick the best from that lot because it will almost certainly tell you it fits better than it really does (in terms of how well you can generalise the results more broadly).

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the objective of your analysis. You said you have 11 predictors, four of which are sociodemographic variables. Is your initial objective to determine which of the 11 predictors make the best mix of variables for predicting your dependent variable or to investigate the crude association of each of the predictor variables with the dependent variable? If the former, then you may need to build some multivariable linear regression model (hierarchical or other based on the theory regarding the relationship amongst the variables) including sociodemographic variables. In fact, this may be preceded by selection of variables for inclusion into the multivariable model based on some statistical criteria and theoretical reasoning. Whether the sample size is enough for multivariable analysis must also be considered here. If the latter, you may do simple linear regression only taking the predictor variables of interest one at a time.

Comment: Actually I read a paper in which there were four variables and the author adopted simple regression for each variable to predict  dependent variable. However In another paper there were sixteen variables and a hierarchical regression was adopted to predict dependent variable. Hence, I think with fewer variables the simple regression is preferred and with more variables the hierarchical regression is preferred. Do you think such inference could be true?

Comment: Still your objective matters. If you want the effect of one variable to be adjusted for the effect of other variables, simple regression would not serve that purpose.